# Spring Boot Not Using UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to configure a Spring Boot 1.2.5 application for JPA authentication using annotations and it appears to be always using the in-memory provider.

The application:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClubBooksApplication {

  protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClubBooksApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I have played around with the order but it always seems to configure the in-memory provider. I feel like I could be missing a piece of configuration but this pattern matches the samples I found in my searches.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)   // After in memory
//@Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)           // Before in memory
//@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)        // Not unique
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 50)   // Before in memory
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private  PasswordEncoder    passwordEncoder;
  protected final Logger      logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    logger.info(String.format("configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder: %s", userDetailsService));

    super.configure(auth);

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }
```

Here is the log output. You can see it is configuring the `UserDetailsService` before displaying the generated password. Based on my digging into the code, it appears to only configure the in-memory provider if no other provider is configured but setting the `UserDetailsService` configures a DAO provider.

```
2015-08-20 11:19:24.187  INFO 42332 --- [ost-startStop-1] yConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c647e8e8 : configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder: com.wstrater.server.clubBooks.server.service.impl.UserLoginDetailServiceImpl@46f0f40a
2015-08-20 11:19:24.226  INFO 42332 --- [ost-startStop-1] yConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c647e8e8 : passwordEncoder
2015-08-20 11:19:24.410  INFO 42332 --- [ost-startStop-1] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: 838a7ab0-3bd0-4e87-94ca-de2dfd34b965

2015-08-20 11:19:24.526  INFO 42332 --- [ost-startStop-1] yConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c647e8e8 : configure HttpSecurity
```

I have included Actuator in the app and when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/mappings`, I am prompted with `BasicAuth` despite configuring form based authentication. The user/generated password works for `BasicAuth`. My `UserDetailsService` implementation is not called.

Configuring `HttpSecurity`. This method is called after the in-memory provider is created and the generated password is displayed so I doubt it impacts the provider configuration. The one thing I find interesting is that I get prompted for `BasicAuth` despite specifying `formLogin()`. I bring this up since I am also having issues with mapping my controllers. I think it is unrelated but what do I know.

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    logger.info("configure HttpSecurity");

    super.configure(http);

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/public/**")
          .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**")
          .authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/web/**")
          .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
          .fullyAuthenticated();

    http.formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .usernameParameter("userName")
          .passwordParameter("password")
          .failureUrl("/login?error")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/web/")
          .permitAll()
        .and().logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
          .permitAll()
        .and().rememberMe();
  }
```

I can see my controllers are being loaded by Spring since they are listed using `http://localhost:8080/beans` but I do not see the mappings in `http://localhost:8080/mappings`.

My login controller is rather simple.

```
@Controller
@Path("/login")
public class LoginWebController {

  @GET
  public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam(required = false) String error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
  }

}
```

Thanks, Wes.

Comment: Why should spring be able to understand the `@Path` annotation from JAX-WS. You are mixing 2 technologies in a single class that don't match. Replace `@Path` and `@GET` with `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: Yup. I fixed that. I was just working on a Jetty/Jersey project when I started this. Still getting `BasicAuth` instead of a form login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this after working around and/or avoiding the problem so I may have done several things to solve the issue but I believe it is as simple as removing the call to `super.configure(http);`. This sets up basic auth.

Wes.